# Java: Implementation of PHP's ord() yields different results for chars beyond ASCII

Tags: java, php, character-encoding

I'm trying to write a Java equivalent to PHP's [`ord()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php):

```
public static int ord(char c) {
    return (int) c;
}

public static int ord(String s) {
    return s.length() > 0 ? ord(s.charAt(0)) : 0;
}
```

This seems to works well for characters with an ordinal value of up to `127`, i.e. within ASCII. However, PHP returns `195` (and higher) for characters from the extended ASCII table or beyond. A comment by [Mr. Llama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477563/mr-llama) to [the answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32911670/3316645) explains this as follows:

> To elaborate, the reason é showed ASCII 195 is because it's actually a two-byte character (UTF-8), the first byte of which is ASCII 195. – Mr. Llama

I hence changed my `ord(char c)` method to mask out all but the most significant byte:

```
public static int ord(char c) {
    return (int) (c & 0xFF);
}
```

Still, the results differ. Two examples:

- `ord('é')` (U+00E9) gives `195` in PHP while my Java function yields `233`
- `ord('⸆')` (U+2E06) gives `226` in PHP while my Java function yields `6`

I manged to get the same behavior *for the method that accepts a `String`* by first turning the `String` into a `byte` array, explicitly using UTF-8 encoding:

```
public static int ord(String s) {
    return s.length() > 0 ? ord((char)s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)[0]) : 0;
}
```

However, using the method that accepts a `char` still behaves as before and I could not yet find a solution for that. In addition, I don't understand why the change actually worked: `Charset.defaultCharset()` returns `UTF-8` on my platform anyway. So...

- **How can I make my function behave similar to that of PHP?**
- **Why does the change to `ord(String s)` actually work?**

Explanatory answers are much appreciated, as I want to grasp what's going on exactly.

Comment: Java appears to be correct; 233 is indeed the code for `é`: http://www.ascii-code.com/.  195 is the code for `Ã`, so who knows WTF is going on under-the-hood in PHP.

Comment: Actually, seems to be heavily related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575721/ord-doesnt-work-with-utf-8

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth that is correct, PHP's `ord()` does not work correctly with characters outside the ASCII range. However, I'm trying to replicate that behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java a [`char` is a UTF-16 code unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236364/why-java-char-uses-utf-16). Converting UTF-16 to UTF-8 is not just `& 0xFF`, for instance `01FF` in UTF-16 is `C7 BF` in UTF-8, so the PHP `ord()` should give `0xC7` (199), yet `0x01FF & 0xFF` is 255.

The `String` version works because it is actually transforming to UTF-8.

The simplest way is to reverse your two overloads, since `String` has a convenient method to get UTF-8:

```
public static int ord(String s) {
    return s.length() > 0 ? (s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)[0] & 0xff) : 0;
}
```

and [convert the `char` to a `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172420/how-to-convert-a-char-to-a-string):

```
public static int ord(char c) {
    return c < 0x80 ? c : ord(Character.toString(c))
}
```

---

While this works, it is not quite efficient because of the unnecessary char→String→int conversion. The first byte of the UTF-8 encoding of a Unicode code-point `c` can be actually be found using:

```
if (c < 0x80) {
    return c;
} else if (c < 0x800) {
    return 0xc0 | c >> 6;
} else if (c < 0x10000) {
    return 0xe0 | c >> 12; 
} else {
    return 0xf0 | c >> 18;
}
```

You may also want to read [What is Unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-is-unicode-utf-8-utf-16) for some background information.

Comment: Ah, that explains everything! Terrific answer, thank you. I'm using Java for about 3 years now and never knew it used UTF-16 internally. I'll make sure to read through the linked references carefully.